# Displaying retrieved value in combobox

Tags: c#, vb.net, combobox

I am accesing value from database and displaying them on form ,i have successfully displayed retrived value in textbox and radiobox but  i am not able to display them in combbox .
In combox items I have values(1 2 3 4) in this combox i want to display fetched value from database for eg. i accesed value 4 for combbox then it should display 4 value selected in it .
how could i achieve this?

```
public EditQuestionMaster(int qid_value)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string columns = db.GetEditQuestions(qid_value);
    string[] coldata=columns.Split('~');

    txtQuestion.Text = coldata[1];
    txtOption1.Text = coldata[2];
    txtOption2.Text = coldata[3];
    txtOption3.Text = coldata[4];
    txtOption4.Text = coldata[5];
    string a = coldata[6];

    if (a == "1")
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = true;
    }
    else if (a == "2")
    {
        radioButton2.Checked = true; 
    }
    else if (a == "3")
    {
        radioButton3.Checked = true;
    }
    else if (a == "4")
    {
        radioButton4.Checked = true;
    }
        cmbMarks.ValueMember = coldata[7];//in cmbMarks.ValueMember i am getting fetched value but it is not displaying in combbox ,where i am wrong?           
}
```

GetEditQuestions(qid_value) Code

```
public string GetEditQuestions(int qid)
{
    string data = "";
    try
    {
        string sql = "select QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions where QID IN(" + qid + ") ";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, acccon);
        rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rs.Read())
        {
            data = rs[0].ToString() + "~" + rs[1].ToString() + "~" + rs[2].ToString() + "~" + rs[3].ToString() + "~" + rs[4].ToString() + "~" + rs[5].ToString() + "~" + rs[6].ToString() + "~" + rs[7].ToString() + "$";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
    }
    return data;
}
```

Thanks in Advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmbMarks.Text = coldata[7].Substring(1)
```

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx). The `.Substring(1)` is assuming that `coldata[7]` is a string with a $ as the first character.

Comment: using this i am gettin `$` sign also with that data how do i remove it if i dont want to change query?

Comment: @Durga There are a number of ways to trim off characters from a string. I'll edit my answer for an easy one for your case

Comment: I am getting answer like `data$` and using this `cmbMarks.Text = coldata[7].Substring(1)` i am getting answer as `$`,how do i get answer as `data` only

Comment: I got exact data using `TrimToEnd('$')` triming method ,Thanks .